# How to scroll down a webpage, which is a .pdf file that was opened on Google Chrome by Selenium Webdriver, with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pdf, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scroll down on a web page that had been opened on Google Chrome using selenium webdriver, but this page is actually a .pdf file, and I guess because of that my solutions are not working, which are the following:

`browser.find_element('body').send_keys(Keys.END)`

and I also tried

`browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")`

I need to scroll down the page so I can use `browser.save_screenshot('image.png')` to get the picture I need.
Could someone help me doing this on Python 3 ?

Comment: If the URL ends with ".pdf", the webdriver can't do anything with it. There is no DOM to communicate with.

Comment: Just download the PDF and then you can use other libraries/tools to do whatever you need to do.